# Error within mysql, An alias was previously found

Tags: mysql

An alias was previously found. (near "genreID" at position 83)

```
UPDATE book SET name='douglas adams' description='ffff' rating=1 yearReleased=2001 genreID=9 authorID=11 WHERE bookID=11
```

This was the query that was outputted outputted i cant find any problems with it
If someone could see anything wrong with it it would be appreciated

Comment: You're missing commas between each SET. It should be `UPDATE book SET name='douglas', description='ffff', ... WHERE bookID=11`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong put `,` after every column name

```
UPDATE book SET name='douglas adams',
                description='ffff',
                rating=1,
                yearReleased=2001,
                genreID=9, 
                authorID=11
WHERE bookID=11
```

**General Syntax:**

```
UPDATE table
SET column1 = expression1,
    column2 = expression2,
    ...
[WHERE conditions];
```

Comment: Thank you. Makes me feel like an idiot ive been overthinking it this whole time. Ughhh something so small. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of query is wrong. In update query, always put comma(,) seperator if having multiple columns to edit. The actual query will be :

```
UPDATE book SET name='douglas adams', description='ffff', rating=1, yearReleased=2001, genreID=9, authorID=11 WHERE bookID=11
```

You can find more about update query by using this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html